# How to write a snabbdom loader in webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack

I start to work with a `snabbdom` technology. The binder, that I use for my projects, is webpack. When I try to run the project on node.JS ('`npm run build`'), it shows me the mistake:

```
ERROR in ./app/main.js
Module parse failed: D:\User\webWorkspace\snabbdom\snabbwebpack\app\main.js Line
 3: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| "use strict";
|
| import snabbdom from 'snabbdom';
| import counter from './counter';
|
```

Are somebody here know how to write a snabbdom loader in webpack.config.js file?

Comment: Show your `package.json`, `webpack.config.js` and `.babelrc` files

Answer (score 0):

It's not about `snabbdom`, but ES2015 syntax. You need a `babel-loader`:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-core

npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev

echo '{ "presets": ["es2015"] }' > .babelrc
```

And in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: there is a babel-loader in my config file:

Comment: And do you have  `babel-preset-es2015`  ?

Comment: thanks for advise, but this modules are already installed and the same info written in my config file, but its still don't build the bundle

Comment: @DmitryCalantarov  
Show your package.json, webpack.config.js and .babelrc files

Answer (score 0):

```
webpack.config.js

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/main.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: path.join(__dirname, 'es6'),
                query: {
                  presets: 'es2015',
                },
            },


        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Avoid publishing files when compilation fails
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    stats: {
        // Nice colored output
        colors: true
    },
    // Create Sourcemaps for the bundle
    devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
  "name": "webpack-snabbdom",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A small demo project that shows how to use webpack for client-side development",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "snabbdom": "^0.3.1",
    "snabbdom-jsx": "^0.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "watch": "^0.17.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.12",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.6.4",
    "webpack-sources": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "flyd": "^0.2.0",
    "snabbdom": "^0.2.8",
    "stats-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue myself and decided to go directly to the [snabbdom-jsx](https://github.com/yelouafi/snabbdom-jsx/blob/master/.babelrc) directory to get a hint. One preset snabbdom-jsx's .babelrc had, that I did not have, is the `"stage-2"` preset. I put it in and viola! Your .babelrc should look like the following in order to work:

`{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"]
}`

Alternatively, while I did not try it, putting the following in your Webpack config,

`{test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2', 'react]
                }
            }`

Should work as well.

All in all, modifying my .babelrc fixed it for me. The compiler no longer complained, and I am currently enjoying snabbdom-jsx.

(Don't forget to run the proper npm-install as well, i.e. `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2`)